# Prevent more than one space between words

Tags: javascript, whitespace, detection, keyevent, preventdefault

I have a function that prevents people putting numbers or any symbol but letters onkeypress into a text box due to ongoing problems with data entry.

```
<td><input type="text" name="name" onkeypress="return isAlfa(event)"></td>
```

Now some staff for reasons unknown put two spaces between words at random times. So I need to prevent them putting more than one space between words. I want to do this in the same function, but it keeps breaking.

```
function isAlfa(evt) {
  evt = (evt || window.event);
  var charCode = (evt.which || evt.keyCode);

  if ((charCode > 32)
    && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90)
    && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)
  ) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

How can I prevent them entering more than one space between words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be try to use something like this. on your `keypress` event try to check the last value by using `string` `substr` method and if that gives you a space and current code is also a Space then prevent or do whatever you want to do with input.

```js
function checkstuff(event){
  if (event.target.value.substr(-1) === ' ' && event.code === 'Space') {
    console.log('space pressed in sequence');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='text' onkeypress="checkstuff(event)">
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything, no alert when I double space

Comment: jsfiddle works well, perhaps the problem is how I added the code to my function?

Comment: let me check if i can fit my code in yours and get that working.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/Lrs1cjyw/ here we are not only checking for double space but also correcting it as well so that if user is data entry person so input field should omit extra space itself. another change I did is declare `evt`  as local variable inside function scope instead of defining it as global one like it is defined in your code snippet.

Comment: @Kilisi ... this approach will fail in many situations like 1) whitespaces are not just " " 2) not just concatenating a whitespace to an input value, but actually entering a whitespace e.g somewhere in the middle of an an input value right before or after another WS.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I understand what you mean. But for my specific problem the user just needs to enter a first name and last name copying from a piece of paper, no copy/pasting or anything like that, and no reason to do other whitespaces

Comment: @Kilisi ... belief me, as a developer, pretending what a user might/will do, does not come close to what in reality a user in addition will come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Neglecting all the other helpful suggestions and comments and strictly following the OP's requirements one has to ...

1. Adapt the return condition in a way that takes into account if, with the current keystroke, a whitespace sequence is going to be created.
2. Thus one has to implement a method that determines exactly that.
3. There might be some possible helper methods too.
4. code example ...

```js
function isWhiteSpace(char) {
  return (/\s/).test(char);
}
function willCreateWhitespaceSequence(evt) {
  var willCreateWSS = false;
  if (isWhiteSpace(evt.key)) {
  
    var elmInput = evt.currentTarget;
    var content = elmInput.value;

    var posStart = elmInput.selectionStart;
    var posEnd = elmInput.selectionEnd;

    willCreateWSS = (
         isWhiteSpace(content[posStart - 1] || '')
      || isWhiteSpace(content[posEnd] || '')
    );
  }
  return willCreateWSS;
}

function isAlfa(evt) {

  evt = (evt || window.event);
  var charCode = (evt.which || evt.keyCode);

  return ((
       (charCode > 32)
    && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90)
    && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)

  ) || willCreateWhitespaceSequence(evt)) ? false : true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" onkeypress="return isAlfa(event)"/>
```

Comment: But why is there a dot `.` in the place of the first white space? I mean, if I try to put a double white space in the input field, the first white space character is replaced by a dot. I mean, I need to press the second white space immediately after the first one.

Comment: @DariuszLegizynski ... A dot which all of a sudden appears as first character of a very quickly typed double space sequence (1st this ... `' '` ... then all of a sudden that ... `'. '`) most probably is due to an autocorrect function of either the keyboard or the browser or the operation system. Such a feature of cause is not covered by the above provided approach which does a single character lookbehind into the current input value each time a whitespace was typed. You might countercheck it by typing the whitespaces more slowly.

Comment: Of course, you are right. Not used to a mac, thats why. I finally found it out, but forgot to remove my comment. Thanks anyway for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

This code will prevent multiple white spaces, that is, it will only allow 1 space and it will prevent two or more white spaces. You can configure the amount of white space you want to deny. I am not the author of the original code, but I made the modifications to make it work properly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Your-title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="YourInputName">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="YourInputName">

<script>
  var field = document.querySelector('[name="YourInputName"]');

  field.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    var userName = field.value;
    userName = userName.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
    field.value = userName;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than listening for and evaluating each key press it would be far simpler just to react to any and all input and then sanitise whatever was entered via a RegExp.

Example:

```
<input type=text id=myfield />
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('#myfield').addEventListener('input', evt => {
    evt.target.value = evt.target.value.replace(/[^a-z\s]/ig, '').replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
});
```

That first replaces all non-letters and spaces with nothing, then replaces sequences of 2 or more spaces with a single space.

Comment: Yep, I get that, but a bunch of other things happen between typing and the form being submitted or even the text box being completed. So unless I want to change a bunch of things, it makes more sense (to me) to do it onkeypress

Comment: OK sure, but what if I paste a value into your field via the mouse? Your event won't fire.

Comment: Pasting is fine, the way they get the data is copying off a physical piece of paper, they can't paste from there

Comment: In addition I would recommend to run the sanitizing in a *throttled* mode. Thus one limits the amount of computation and does not "annoy" the user while e.g. typing.

Comment: @PeterSeliger yes, this is a good solution.... for another problem... I need it done onkeypress. If it was a matter of sanitising after submission, I wouldn't use javascript.